# Is there a global rendered function in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, onload, iron-router

I'm wondering if there is something like a global version of the Template.myTemplate.Rendered in Meteor. I would like to attach all of my global GUI specific Javascript (scroll-top animations, custom checkboxes etc.) without attaching it to every single template manually. I tried calling it from the layout, but it didn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong? I'm using iron router btw.

Cheers & thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a layout that is shared across many pages or even your whole app you can also attach handlers to that. A template that embeds another template that embeds another template is fine, each of those will get a `rendered` event.

Answer (score 4):

Attach them to body

```
Template.body.rendered = function (){
//do stuff
}
```

or from Meteor 1.0.4

```
Template.body.onRendered(function(){
//do stuff
})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer - doesn't do anything for me though..? body.rendered doesnt get called at all, body.onRendered throws an "undefined is not a function error" although i'm on the newest update...any hints?

Comment: ```Template.body.onRendered``` not body.onRendered, its imposible to not work http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_body . I hope you have these helpers under ```client``` folder.

Comment: Sorry - but for me as well - it doesn't work. `Template.body.onRendered` in the `client` folder is not called.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is an issue with Iron Router and the body.

```
Template.body.onRendered(function(){
//do stuff
})
```

will work but you have to specify the body tag somewhere and use "Custom Router Rendering"

```
<body>{{>Router}}</body>
```

Comment: I know there was a problem with Iron-Router and body events. This package fixes it:

https://github.com/gwendall/meteor-body-events